# Joda Time in Eclipse: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, eclipse, jodatime, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to use the Joda Time library for my Android app to have ISO 8601 formatted dates.  I followed [this guide](http://crafted-software.blogspot.com/2011/07/adding-libraries-to-eclipse.html) to load it into my project and I've imported the classes I'm using.  Eclipse seems to recognize everything just fine as it auto-completed my imports.  But when I run, it seems unable to find something.  The first message I see is this:

```
06-06 13:53:38.831: W/dalvikvm(4172): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/joda/time/DateTime;)
```

followed by some more VFY messages, then this:

```
06-06 13:53:38.911: E/dalvikvm(4172): Could not find class 'org.joda.time.DateTime', referenced from method ...
```

and then this:

```
06-06 13:53:40.661: I/dalvikvm(4172): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.joda.time.DateTime
```

and the VM aborts

Is the guide that I followed for setting up Joda Time missing something?  Any ideas what I could do to get this library working? Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure that you create a libs dir in your project directory and add the jar in there.

Then add the jar file as normal (in project properties)

Comment: "Then add the jar file as normal (in project properties)" - Right click it in the Project Explorer, select Build Path > Add to Build Path

Comment: I was missing the libs directory - working fine now. Thank you!

Comment: happened to me after updating ADT and Eclipse